# is there a way to create datasource in spring boot only after hitting the endpoint instead of in start up with @Configuration annotation

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, datasource

I have a requirement that, i need to create a datasource in the spring boot application to make a DB operations.
Currently i am using JpaRepository to do this using the dataSource created programmatically with @Configuration annotated class.

`HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();`

`dataSource.setJdbcUrl("<url with the host name, port and database>"); dataSource.setUsername("userName");`

`dataSource.setPassword("xxxxxx");`

`dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver"); // Set the PostgreSQL driver class explicitly dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(1);`

`dataSource.setMinimumIdle(5);`

`return dataSource;`

While application startup, the datasource is configured and working fine.

But my requirement in the real timeis,
The datasource properties(DB name, usename, password etc) are not available in the application startUp, when ever any one of the end point is triggered from the rest controller, based on one mandatory header, i will make an one service call to get the db details and need to create a datasource for first time and cached for further usage.

For Spring boot in the internet every whare it is suggested that to configure the data source in application start up with @Configuration annotation only.
Can any one help on my requirement to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually to prevent bean from startup initialization you can use @Lazy annotation, but in your particular case to provide db details you can do the following:

```
@Service
@Lazy(true)
public class DynamicDataSourceService {

    public DataSource createDataSource(String jdbcUrl, String username, String password) {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
        dataSource.setMinimumIdle(5);

        return dataSource;
    }
}

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private DynamicDataSourceService dataSourceService;

    @GetMapping("/endpoint")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleRequest(@RequestHeader("dbInfo") String dbInfo) {
        // validation logic based on 'dbInfo' header  
        DataSource dataSource = dataSourceService.createDataSource(jdbcUrl, username, password);
        // your business logic here 
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

This approach does not include caching of the DataSource instances for follow-up requests, but if you need it for some reason you can use Spring capabilities for caching.

Comment: I followed this approach, but while start up getting error like "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured." and application is failed to start

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: you can apply @Lazy to your `DynamicDataSourceService`

Comment: Even after applying, the same exception not able to up the application, it is expecting to have DB details 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Comment: alternatively you can exclude the data source from autoconfiguration and check again
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
so that you take full control over configuring your data source.

Comment: No luck getting below error even i changed annotation to Configuration from Service

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
 - com.xxx.xxxxxxxx.repository.utils.DynamicDataSourceService

Comment: Did you try to exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` not `DynamicDataSourceService ` right? Your error output suggests that you tried to exclude an incorrect class.